# jquery checkbox for approve and reject

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, checkbox

i have created a logic in which i have to approve and reject users...

but issue is say, when i approve 2 users now but i have to reject 1 user and when i do the checkbox(approve)of other gets unchecked

and when i use "id" the logic only works for 1st entry and when use "class" it works for all at once

what can be the correct logic for approve and reject

```
$('.approve_chk').on('click', function () {
    var pswd = prompt("enter password to confirm");
    if (pswd == 'approve') {
        alert('APPROVED');
    } else {
        alert('NOT APPROVED');
        $(".approve_chk").prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$('.reject_chk').on('click', function () {
    var pswd = prompt("enter password to confirm");
    if (pswd == 'reject') {
        alert('REJECTED');
        $(".approve_chk").prop('checked', false);

    } else {
        alert('NOT REJECTED');
        $(".reject_chk").prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Add html code so that we can see the exact issue. you have to use `$(this)` anyway

Comment: there are two checkboxes in a table   <td><input type="checkbox" id="approve" class="approve_chk"  data-id="{{$leave->id}}"></td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="reject" class="reject_chk"  data-id="{{$leave->id}}"></td>            as i am viewing mysql data in table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have multiple same `classes` so use `$(this)`

```
$('.approve_chk').on('click', function () {
    var pswd = prompt("enter password to confirm");
    if (pswd == 'approve') {
        alert('APPROVED');
    } else {
        alert('NOT APPROVED');
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$('.reject_chk').on('click', function () {
    var pswd = prompt("enter password to confirm");
    if (pswd == 'reject') {
        alert('REJECTED');
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.approve_chk').prop('checked', false);

    } else {
        alert('NOT REJECTED');
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Working snippet:

```js
$('.approve_chk').on('click', function () {
        var pswd = prompt("enter password to confirm");
        if (pswd == 'approve') {
            alert('APPROVED');
        } else {
            alert('NOT APPROVED');
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
    
    $('.reject_chk').on('click', function () {
        var pswd = prompt("enter password to confirm");
        if (pswd == 'reject') {
            alert('REJECTED');
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.approve_chk').prop('checked', false);
    
        } else {
            alert('NOT REJECTED');
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="approve" class="approve_chk" data-id="1">Approve
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="reject" class="reject_chk" data-id="1">Reject
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="approve" class="approve_chk" data-id="2">Approve
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="reject" class="reject_chk" data-id="2">Reject
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

generate the dynamic ID of each row example id="example1" id="example2" id="example3" and so on, and onClick pass that number of the row onclick="myfunction(1)" onclick="myfunction(2)" onclick="myfunction(3)" and so on. then on your function get the number passed on click and concatinate with "example"(your id prefix).

Answer (score 0):

I asume your html has multiple `.approve_chk` and `.reject_chk`. You have to make sure you are setting the prop for the current checkbox. Your code now updates all checkboxes with these classes.

```
$('.approve_chk').on('click', function () {
    var pswd = prompt("enter password to confirm");
    if (pswd == 'approve') {
        alert('APPROVED');
    } else {
        alert('NOT APPROVED');
        this.prop('checked', false);
    //  ^ Refers to the clicked element.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to select the checkbox to uncheck by referencing the data-id values:

```
$('.approve_chk').on('click', function () {
    var pswd = prompt("enter password to confirm");
    if (pswd == 'approve') {
        alert('APPROVED');
    } else {
        var thisId = $(this).data(id);
        alert('NOT APPROVED');
        $(".approve_chk[data-id='" + thisId + '").prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$('.reject_chk').on('click', function () {
    var pswd = prompt("enter password to confirm");
    if (pswd == 'reject') {
        alert('REJECTED');
        var thisId = $(this).data(id);
        $(".approve_chk[data-id='" + thisId + '").prop('checked', false);

    } else {
        alert('NOT REJECTED');
        $(".reject_chk").prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```